# Different counters for theorems, lemmas, definitions,

Tags: theorems, lemma

I don't know how I can create different counters for theorems, lemmas, definitions, observations, corollaries, examples and exercises.
I'd like to have the numeration of these as **chapter.section.subsection.number**, where "number" stays for the number of theorem, lemma, ... .
For example I'd like to have something like that:

**Theorem (Pytagora) --- 1.1.1.1**,

**Lemma (Zorn) --- 1.1.1.1**,

**Theorem (Cayley--Hamilton) --- 1.1.1.2**,

**Corollary (of Theorem 1.1.1.2) --- 1.1.1.2.a**,

**Definition (Cauchy's succession) --- 1.1.1.1**.

I hope in you help, Thank you so much
Best Regards

Comment: Then please show us how you define your theorems? A normal `\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]` would be enough to make the first one.

Comment: Thanks for answered me. I definine theorems like so: 
`\newcommand{\namedtheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{namedtheoreminner}[theorem]{\protect\namedtheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
 {%
  \renewcommand{\namedtheoremname}{#1}%
 \begin{namedtheoreminner}%
 }
 {\end{namedtheoreminner}}`

Comment: What is the reasoning for using inner here? Perhaps you should make a full minimal example such that others can get a better idea as to what you are doing. I also did a mistake in my first comment, it should have said `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]`

Comment: I solved my problem. Thank you. Later, I'll answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my question:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}

%(Re)newcommands

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

%New 8 counters

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[subsection]

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection]

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[subsection]

\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}[subsection]

%New Theorems

\newcommand{\namedtheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{namedtheoreminner}[theorem]{\protect\namedtheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedtheoremname}{#1}%
\begin{namedtheoreminner}%
}
{\end{namedtheoreminner}}

%New Definitions

\newcommand{\nameddefinitionname}{}
\newtheorem{nameddefinitioninner}[definition]{\protect\nameddefinitionname}
\newenvironment{nameddefinition}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\nameddefinitionname}{#1}%
\begin{nameddefinitioninner}%
}
{\end{nameddefinitioninner}}

%New Lemmas

\newcommand{\namedlemmaname}{}
\newtheorem{namedlemmainner}[lemma]{\protect\namedlemmaname}
\newenvironment{namedlemma}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedlemmaname}{#1}%
\begin{namedlemmainner}%
}
{\end{namedlemmainner}}

%New Corollaries

\newcommand{\namedcorollaryname}{}
\newtheorem{namedcorollaryinner}[corollary]{\protect\namedcorollaryname}
\newenvironment{namedcorollary}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedcorollaryname}{#1}%
\begin{namedcorollaryinner}%
}
{\end{namedcorollaryinner}}

%New Propositions

\newcommand{\namedpropositionname}{}
\newtheorem{namedpropositioninner}[proposition]{\protect\namedpropositionname}
\newenvironment{namedproposition}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedpropositionname}{#1}%
\begin{namedpropositioninner}%
}
{\end{namedpropositioninner}}


%New Examples

\newcommand{\namedexamplename}{}
\newtheorem{namedexampleinner}[example]{\protect\namedexamplename}
\newenvironment{namedexample}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedexamplename}{#1}%
\begin{namedexampleinner}%
}
{\end{namedexampleinner}}


%New Exercises

\newcommand{\namedexercisename}{}
\newtheorem{namedexerciseinner}[exercise]{\protect\namedexercisename}
\newenvironment{namedexercise}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedexercisename}{#1}%
\begin{namedexerciseinner}%
}
{\end{namedexerciseinner}}

%New Observations

\newcommand{\namedobservationname}{}
\newtheorem{namedobservationinner}[observation]{\protect\namedobservationname}
\newenvironment{namedobservation}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namedobservationname}{#1}%
\begin{namedobservationinner}%
}
{\end{namedobservationinner}}



\title{Theorem Proof, Stack}

\author{Name, Surname}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Theorems}
\subsection{Theorems}
\begin{namedtheorem}{First Theorem}
Statement.
\end{namedtheorem}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{nameddefinition}{First Definition}

\end{nameddefinition}

\begin{nameddefinition}{Second Definition: Cauchy's Succession}
\end{nameddefinition}

\begin{namedlemma}{Zorn's Lemma}
Statement.
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}
\end{namedlemma}

\end{document}
```

Observe this:

```
%New 8 counters

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[subsection]

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection]

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]

\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[subsection]

\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}[subsection]
```

In this way it is possible create new counters and then use themselves like so:

```
% This is the main template for particular \LeTeX--Functions %

\newcommand{\namednewcountername}{}
\newtheorem{namednewcounterinner}[newcounter]{\protect\namednewcountername}
\newenvironment{namednewcounter}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\namednewcountername}{#1}%
\begin{namednewcounterinner}%
}
{\end{namednewcounterinner}}
```

Here You can substutuite newcounter with theorem, lemma, proposition, ... .

**THANK YOU**